# Charge inside a surface with a "non-gaussian" field?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

I read in a book that gauss law is just a statement for the inverse square law. ( As the $r^2$ terms would cancel with the area $4 \pi r^2$.)

Suppose I take a hypothetical field of

$$
E= \frac{1-e^{-ar}}{4π\epsilon r^2}.
$$
(created by a certain charge distribution) Let this field be radial for simplicity. Now as the magnitude of this field does not fall with $r^2$ ,gauss law should be invalid to use.(hypothetical case).
As the field is radial ,"curl rule" would still be valid, but the divergence would not be.
So ,how should we be finding the charge inside of an area ,say with a radius 4π$a^2$. ?

Comment: That is e to the power -ar actually .It didn't come of well in the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Break up the problem with superposition

First, let's split your field into two parts (which is justified by superposition)
\begin{equation}
\vec{E} = \vec{E}_{pp} + \vec{E}_{exp}
\end{equation}
where $\vec{E}_{pp}$ is the field due to a point particle
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{pp} = \frac{Q_1}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2} \hat{e}_r
\end{equation}
(and where I have introduced a parameter $Q_1$ for dimensional consistency),
and where $\vec{E}_{exp}$ is the exponential field
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{exp} = -\frac{Q_2 e^{-ar}}{4\pi \epsilon_0 r^2}
\end{equation}
(and, again, I've introduced a parameter $Q_2$ for dimensional reasons).

We know that $\vec{E}_{pp}$ is generated by point charge $Q_1$ at the origin. So, our task is to determine what charge distribution would lead to $\vec{E}_{exp}$.

#### Use Gauss's law to compute $\rho_{exp}$

Using the [differential form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_law#Differential_form) of Gauss's law
\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}
\end{equation}
where $\rho$ is the charge density, and using the [standard formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) for the divergence of a radial vector field in spherical coordinates,
\begin{equation}
\nabla \cdot (E_r \hat{e}_r) = \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d(r^2 E_r)}{dr}
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho_{exp} &=& \frac{\epsilon_0}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr} \left[r^2 \vec{E}_{exp} \cdot \hat{e}_r \right] \\
&=& - \frac{Q_2}{4\pi} \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d}{dr}\left[e^{-ar}\right] \\
&=& \frac{Q_2a e^{- ar}}{4\pi r^2}
\end{eqnarray}
Actually we've been a little too quick. There is also a point charge with charge $-Q_2$ located at the origin in this charge distribution, because of the fact that the [divergence of $1/r^2$ is proportional a delta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2136837/divergence-of-vecf-frac1r2-hatr). The correct expression is
\begin{equation}
\rho_{exp} = \frac{Q_2a e^{- ar}}{4\pi r^2} - Q_2 \delta^3(r)
\end{equation}

#### Summary

To summarize, the charge distribution is a superposition of

- A point charge at the origin with charge $Q_1$, plus
- A point charge with charge $-Q_2$ at the origin, plus
- A smooth charge distribution
  $$
   \frac{Q_2 a e^{-a r}}{4\pi r^2}
  $$

You could repeat this procedure to determine the charge density given any electric field $\vec{E}$.

---

#### Alternative method: use the integral form of Gauss's law

You could also use the integral form of Gauss's law to get $\rho_{exp}$ as follows.

By spherical symmetry, the flux integral through a surface of radius $R$ is
\begin{eqnarray}
\oint \vec{E} \cdot d{\vec{A}} &=& \left(\vec{E}\cdot \hat{e}_r\right) 4\pi R^2 \\
&=& -\frac{Q_2 e^{-a R}}{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^2} \times 4\pi R^2 \\
&=& - \frac{Q_2 e^{- a R}}{\epsilon_0}
\end{eqnarray}
Then using Gauss's law we calculate the charge enclosed inside of $R$
\begin{equation}
Q_{enc}(R) = \epsilon_0 \oint \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{A} = - Q_2 e^{- a R}
\end{equation}
With the integral form, the fact that there is a point charge $-Q_2$ at the origin is perhaps more clear. As $R\rightarrow 0$, the enclosed charge approaches $-Q_2$.

Finally to compute the charge density, note that
\begin{equation}
Q_{enc}(R) = 4\pi \int dr r^2 \rho(r)
\end{equation}
so
\begin{eqnarray}
\rho_{exp}(R) &=& \frac{1}{4\pi R^2}\frac{dQ_{enc}}{dR} \\
&=& \frac{Q_2 e^{-ar} }{4\pi R^2} - Q_2 \delta^3(R)
\end{eqnarray}
which agrees with the expression we got using the differential form.